# DataBindingComplete event for a DataGridView not firing on first row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which is bound to a datasource. I'm catching the DataBindingComplete event to handle some checkbox columns. Everything works fine unless it's the first row in the grid in which case the event does not seem to fire. I'm not handling any other datagridview events and the method is simply:

```
Private Sub DataBindingComplete(ByVal sender As System.Object,
          ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles _
          grdMyGrid.DataBindingComplete

        Dim testvar As String
        testvar = "hi"   'Breakpoint is on this line

End Sub
```

If I tick any of the checkboxes on any row but the first the breakpoint is hit... first row though... nada. Screenshot probably won't make much difference but this is what I'm working with...

[image: DataGridView]

Comment: I could be mistaken as it is unclear “what” you are wanting to capture/do here. I am guessing that you are NOT using the correct event for checking if a cells value is changed or clicked on. Can you [edit] your question to elaborate or explain what you are wanting to capture/Do?

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the code that I'm trying to execute which works perfectly, when the event is raised. It doesn't matter if it's my custom code or that two line assignment, the event isn't being raised for the first row when I check the boxes but it does for all the other rows. The boxes check and uncheck just fine but the event doesn't pop. Focus.

Comment: Sorry, I was _”focused”_ on the idea that you were using the wrong event for whatever you are wanting to do. And I still stand by that. But if you must use the grids `DataBindingComplete` event, then go for it. Sorry for the inconvenience I caused you. Good Luck.

Comment: `DataBindingComplete` is raised after validation. Since the first Row of a DGV is pre-selected, when you click on another Row you cause a validation event - which implies a value has changed - while clicking on a pre-selected Row doesn't (until you move the `CurrentCell`). -- This also implies that you'd have to call `EndEdit()` in `CellContentClick` and `Validate()` in `CellValueChanged` to make it happen, which may suggest you're using the wrong event.

Comment: Ok I give up. "You're using the wrong event" is obviously the answer and I never should have asked this in the first place. Oh btw... you can't read the whole data set and then set read only, colors, etc using a cellcontentclick fyi it has to happen after you re-fill your dataset. Then you process your rows one by one, set the cell colors, read only state and other properties you want based on this or that cell value and drive on. But I forgot, I'm using the wrong event. Case closed.

Comment: Hmm… from your last comment, you sound almost disappointed at finding the answer. You also state that… _”Oh btw... you can't read the whole data set and then set read only, colors, etc using a cellcontentclick fyi”_ … ? … I will not argue that using the grids cellcontentclick event for what you describe is odd but you CAN do it if you want… again it sounds like you are using the wrong event.

Comment: For DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns, you should consume the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged and CellValueChanged. Do whatever you want to do to your underlying data in the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged and refresh the display in the CellValueChanged event. See [DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)